# Dailymotion acces private video through password

Tags: android, video, android-webview, media, dailymotion-api

I want to embed a video which is password protected from daily motion. I know the password as the owner public the password on his site, i want to show that video into my android app without promoting user to enter password, i want to pass the password to video my self through code so user don't need to add the password to watch the video in my app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to fill automatically a password into a video protected. It's a security process used to protect content and it has to be filled manually